# BatchNormalization Layer causing error in converting from .h5 to .onnx

Tags: tensorflow, keras, onnx

I need to convert a `.h5` model to a `.onnx`, but when I use a `BatchNormalization` layer, the code gives the following error:

> TypeError: value "" is not valid attribute data type.

And gives the warning:

> tf executing eager_mode: True
> tf.keras model eager_mode: False
> WARN: No corresponding ONNX op matches the tf.op node keras_learning_phase of type PlaceholderWithDefault
> The generated ONNX model needs run with the custom op supports.

If I don't use this layer, the code runs and the conversion will succeed, but I need this layer.

The code for conversion is:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
import onnx
import keras2onnx

onnx_model_name = 'CNN_T_93_96_V_90_88.onnx'

model = load_model('CNN_T_93_96_V_90_88.h5')

onnx_model = keras2onnx.convert_keras(model, model.name)
onnx.save_model(onnx_model, onnx_model_name)
```

And the line with `BatchNormalization` layer is:

```
model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum, scale=flag, center=flag))
```